# Formatting an encrypted partition

Tags: command-line, encryption

I was looking at some guides about encrypting partions and decide to try it out with a pendrive.  Everything went good until the part of formatting the drive. I'm not an expert working around with console code and that's why I came here.

So... I have this line of code:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext3 -m 1 -O dir_index,filetype,sparse_super /dev/mapper/securebackup
```

I understand that this will format the partition in **ext3** but that wont make it readable in a Windows PC.
So my question is, how can I change this code to format the partition in fat32, for example?

PS. Would this pendrive accessible from an Windows PC using this guide? I can wait for it to be formatted in fat to know but if someone could advance that information...

This is the guide I was following: [GUIDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage)

I do not know how to build it up but woudn't be possible to use a similar command but using `mkfs.vfat` ?

Answer (score 0):

Re read the guide, the LUKS filesystem is windows compatible and encryptable you need to visit the link to FreeOTFE at the beginning of the expert section.

mkfs.vfat is automatically called by mkfs when doing a fat filesystem, do not call directly.